# Convert the string "2016-09-02 12:25:08" into date as 2016-09-02 12:25:08 in Swift

Tags: swift, ios9

I have array of dictionaries with Key and Value. I need to sort an array of dictionaries in descending order based on Date like formate 2016-09-02 12:25:08.

Comment: not defending But Descending Order.

Comment: where have you been stuck at?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the possible solution to sort ArrayOfDictionary by date:

```
    let sortedRostersByDate  = TempArray.sortedArray(comparator: { (obj1, obj2) -> ComparisonResult in


                        var date2:NSDate!
                        var date1:NSDate!

                        if let dict = obj2 as? NSDictionary
                        {
                            if let tempdate2 = df.date(from: dict.object(forKey: "Sectiontitle") as! String)
                            {
                                date2 = tempdate2 as NSDate!
                            }
                        }
                        if let dict = obj1 as? NSDictionary
                        {
                            if let tempdate1 = df.date(from: dict.object(forKey: "Sectiontitle") as! String)
                            {
                                date1 = tempdate1 as NSDate!
                            }
                        }
                        return date2.compare(date1 as Date)


                    })
let SortedArray = NSMutableArray(array: sortedRostersByDate)
```

Here TempArray is array to sort

Comment: if this answer is correct for you than accept it as a right answer.